# Verify smart contract from Python fails because of Cloudflare

Tags: etherscan, verify

I am trying to verify a smart contract in Ropsten automatically with Python but Cloudflare is blocking me (I get a 403 asking me to complete a Captcha). Is there a way to bypass this?

```
url = 'https://api-ropsten.etherscan.io/api'
data = {
    'apikey': ETHERSCAN_API_KEY,
    'module': 'contract',
    'action': 'verifysourcecode',
    'contractaddress': address,
    'sourceCode': content,
    'contractname': 'MyToken',
    'compilerversion': 'v0.8.4+commit.c7e474f2',
    'optimizationUsed': '1',
    'evmversion': '',
    'licenseType': '3',
}
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8'}
result = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)
```

Comment: Use high quality IP address. Your IP address is likely greylisted by CloudFlare because there has been too much malicious activity from your IP address or IP address block.

Comment: Using other tools such as truffle-verify locally works fine. That's node.js but it uses the same API. I also tried verifying with Python from a server and I get a 403

Answer (score 1):

You could try installing a python module named cloudscraper, which will help you bypass the captcha verification process. You will use cloudscraper to create an object which will send your POST request.